# Is it possible to construct a green function of the Dirichlet problem from the green function of the Cauchy problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, greens-function

For the heat equation. Is there a method to obtain the green function of the Dirichlet problem in a rectangular 2D domain from the green function of the Cauchy problem (infinite domain) PDE's?

Comment: Find a solution of the homogenous equation that matches the global Green function on the boundary of the domain and subtract the two.

Comment: Of course, why I didn't think of that. Thanks